# Is an employee responsible for damage to their employer's laptop due to wear and tear?

Tags: germany, startup, hardware, damage

The key cap of my employer's laptop popped off. If I report it to my employer, am I responsible for the cost of fixing the damage?

I know that large companies have It departments for dealing with issues like this but I work for a startup and I'm in my notice period, and I'm concerned they'll try to make me pay for it even though it happened due to being a used laptop and experiencing wear and tear.

I already declined an offer from my boss to buy the laptop so I think he wants to recoup the cost of the laptop.

Comment: There are two different questions here: who is responsible, and how to best handle it. As the company is entirely responsible (it's their property and this isn't inentional damage), if you are on some sort of thin ice this may not be best to bring anyway and just eat the cost of key replacement.  So why would you be worried to raise that?

Comment: Can you just pop it back into place?

Comment: **"Hey Boss, this thing I was provided by the company broke, what should I do?"** - Seems like the most efficient way to get an answer.

Comment: Did you say that your boss offer to sell you the laptop ? For how much ?

Comment: Don't overthink it. Regular wear and tear is normal and it is employer`s responsibility to fix it

Comment: This is not different from asking *"Is an employee responsible for damage to their employer's office chair due to wear and tear?"* and unless there is some significant recklessness involved the answer is a clear no.

Comment: Mentioning it is the thing to do, unless you can easily fix it yourself. Normal wear and tear is normal and not your responsibility. Also, in the case of a keycap, those are usually trivial to fix and replace, and not worth worrying about.

Comment: Don't discount the possibility that what you see as damage is actually a *manufacturing defect* covered by warranty, and thus neither yours nor your employer's responsibility.

Comment: I asked a colleague to show me the bottom of his shoe once, I took a photo of it to compare with the footprint found on my open laptop... What's happens offsite, *stays offsite* though lol

Comment: @bta But it's clearly the employer's responsibility to claim that warranty, because it's their property.

Comment: also, your boss might have proposed you to buy it because it's an old laptop that has virtually no value to him. Instead of just throwing it away for nothing might as well ask if you want it to recoup something

Comment: Do you mean that ***A*** keycap popped off?  Because usually you can just push one of those back on yourself.  If that doesn't work, then usually your IT dept can fix it in a matter of seconds.

Comment: Did the keycap *break* or did it simply come loose? Laptops vary, but many keyboards are designed in such a way that the keycaps can easily pop off so you can clean underneath them or replace them. Chances are you can just reinsert the keycap in its place and it will be like nothing ever happened.

Comment: Broadly no but please note that you didn't call it 'fair wear and tear.'

Answer (score 52):

> The key cap of my employer's laptop popped off. If I report it to my
> employer, am I responsible for the cost of fixing the damage?

No. You are not responsible.

Try not to anticipate problems. Report the issue simply as a matter of fact and ask what should be done.

Comment: Since this is located in Germany, I am _pretty_ confident that the Laptop is a) already "abgeschrieben" (worth 0 Euros) and/or b) covered by insurance. And even if it wasn't: It's a tool. No carpenter that is employed will pay for a broken saw out of his own pocket. They would probably even have a hard time making OP pay if he did it intentionally.

Comment: @Fildor since this is located in a *startup* in Germany, I am *pretty* confident that the managment is trying to offload every substantial cost to the employees (implicityl or explicitly), while retaining some nice numbers for themselves and the company, to keep on having access to easy credit, hanging strong on the ignorance of employees of their rights.

Comment: @EarlGrey **I bet** they'll try something fishy, but let's give them a chance to be better than our experiences :)

Comment: @Fildor You bet? Based on what evidence? This appears to be OP's first job - since they're clearly unaware of how these things work normally. Chances are far greater OP is freaking out about nothing... it's a keycap - they're made to come off. Unless OP *did* do something they aren't supposed to (I've never had a keycap just come off on it's own), they have absolutely nothing to fear here.

Comment: @SnakeDoc based on experience with Startups. But as I said: I am also willing to be positively surprised. And also, yes, it's just a freaking keycap. Viel Lärm um Nichts.

Comment: @Fildor do not mix up accounting value with actual value. Amortization is just a tool to divide the cost of buying the laptop (or whatever good) for several years. But if you need to buy a replacement, that is a new cost that you would not have if the laptop was still working. That a free has an accounting value of 0 (or 1€) does not mean that it has an actual value of 0. Anyway I agree with "this is a tool the employer is responsible for" part.

Comment: Organizations regularly replace computer systems for this sort of reason, they do not last forever, and the warranties expire.

Answer (score 25):

No, making employees liable for damages to work equipment is very difficult in Germany. It's pretty much impossible unless the employer can prove that the employee acted grossly negligent or maliciously.

But that doesn't necessarily stop them from trying. Inexperienced employers (like most startups) might try because they don't know better. Experienced employers dealing with lowly educated employees might also try occasionally because they hope their employees don't know better.

In that case, the escalation path I would recommend is:

1. Googling relevant court cases and showing them to the one making the demand
2. Contacting the *Betriebsrat*
3. Contacting your trade union
4. Contacting a lawyer

Comment: What is  the Betriebsrat ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 It's a German thing. An elected council of workers that enjoys certain privileges enshrined in German labor law. They represent the interests of the workers to the company leadership. One of their duties is to complain if any internal or government regulations for how to treat employees are violated. So if you as an employee think the employer is crossing a line, then the *Betriebsrat* is a group of colleagues who (should) have your back and speak up for you. More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Works_council#Germany

Comment: Not all companies have a Betriebsrat. Smaller companies like startups typically don't.

Comment: ^^ this. Also, 4. should be 1. (_and_ every employee should have a Arbeitsrechtschutzversicherung - tested it, so you don't have to ;) Recommend it, 10/10 )

Comment: I would skip (1) and go straight to the *Betriebsrat*.

Comment: This question seems to be getting ahead of itself. The OP hasn't been asked to pay for the damage. The first action should be to inform the OP's manager of the problem and ask about getting it repaired or replaced. Turning up at your manager's door with a bunch of legal documents or a representative from the trade union is unlikely to result in a fast repair and will probably annoy your manager (even if legally they can't do anything to you in response).

Comment: ^That. I may be out of a limb here, but I propose that normal human communication shouldn't be predicated on threats of legal action...

Comment: @StuartF: sure, but the answer doesn't say start with the legal stuff. It says escalate to that _if_ the startup tries to make the employee pay for the repair.

Answer (score 6):

The general rule in most places is so long as the wear and tear is reasonable, then it's the Employers problem.

For example - I have a laptop and over time (due to lots of use) the mousepad stops working - then it's my Employers problem.

The exception to this is when the wear and tear is due to non-work related issues or negligence.

For example - I take my laptop to my local school fair, to play music for a dance - someone spills juice on it - This is my problem, since I wasn't using it for Work related purposes.

Or - I'm at home, I've left my work laptop on the floor and my toddler gets a hold of it and starts bashing it with a wooden hammer - this is my problem since I was being negligent with it.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this answer in principle, but it seems to answer a different question. Wear & tear, which OP is clearly asking about, is `damage that naturally and inevitably occurs as a result of normal wear or aging`, according to Wikipedia. This kind of damage is *clearly* (very much so in Germany) not the employee's issue. The examples here are certainly not in that category.

Comment: @Anoe I think those examples are being provided as counterexamples, not as examples of normal wear and tear.

Comment: Ah you're right, reading it more carefully your interpretation is fine.

Comment: Generally agree with the principles, but for the specific case of the third example, if my employer expected me to take the laptop home to do work then I'd expect them to accept at least *some* of the liability for avoidable accidents and / or lapses of judgement in the home environment.

Comment: Example / True Story - I took my work laptop home one evening, put my bag on the floor outside to unlock my front door, and promptly forgot about it. I suddenly realised later that evening but it had already been stolen by a passer by. You could argue that was me being careless and I should pay to replace it, *or* maybe my employer should recognise there's a risk of avoidable loss / damage when it leaves the office, but it's infrequent enough that they can more easily absorb the cost rather than tap the employee up for half or more of their monthly salary. In my case, *they* replaced it.

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out in other answers, wear and tear of work equipment is generally the employer's problem. In [germany](/questions/tagged/germany) specifically, the law is even more in the employee's favor: In general, **employees are only (fully) liable for gross negligence**.

It is well-established by court precedent that for all activities that are part of an employee's duty, the employee is *not* liable for damages, even if the employee was negligent - unless the employee was significantly negligent (or acted with malice). The German [Wikipedia article on Arbeitnehmerhaftung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbeitnehmerhaftung) explains this in more detail.
Even in case of significant negligence, liability is often limited.

Additionally, in your case it is not even clear you caused the damage (as the laptop is used, and may have been damaged by the previous user). So to make you liable, your employer would need to establish that

- you actually damaged the laptop, *and*
- you did so out of negligence (i.e. it was not just regular wear)

No employer is going to bother with that, they will just eat the cost.

---

To address your specific concerns:

> I know that large companies have It departments for dealing with
> issues like this but I work for a startup and I'm in my notice period,
> and I'm concerned they'll try to make me pay for it [...]

Try not to worry about problems before they become relevant :-). If your company does not have a dedicated IT department, they must still be someone who is responsible for the equipment. Find out who that is, talk to them, and hear what they say.

> I already declined an offer from my boss to buy the laptop so I think
> he wants to recoup the cost of the laptop.

While that is possible, it does seem rather far-fetched - a) a used laptop is not worth a lot, so there is not a lot to "recoup" anyway, and b) your boss will not be able to claim the full cost of the laptop if only one key is damaged.

Also, it is equally possible your boss just wanted to do you a favor by offering you a laptop for little money.

While it is good to try to anticipate problems, try to not assume the worst :-).

Answer (score 1):

From a combination of legal and practical hurdles, an employee is rarely liable financially for anything but wilful damage.

Legally, a duty to take reasonable care of goods exists, but reasonable care isn't synonymous with the absence of damage to the goods, and the standard of reasonable care to which an employee will be held is low and basically amounts to not doing anything deliberate to damage the goods.

The reason this policy exists is twofold.

Firstly, employees are often in charge of goods whose value is completely disproportionate to the employee's own resources, and the courts are unwilling to get involved in an overall arrangement which essentially consists of employers handing out valuable and delicate goods to paupers, and then trying to squeeze those paupers dry when something accidentally goes wrong.

Secondly, the employer has relatively arbitrary power to compel expensive goods to be handled and used in circumstances where risks are obviously non-zero, including in circumstances where it may make overall sense for the employer to take the risk (given the value of the work done, and the potential to pool many risks), but it wouldn't make sense for the employee to take that risk. The employee usually isn't in a position to evaluate and manage the risk, or to decide whether to accept the risk. For this reason, courts don't tend to consider the employee as the appropriate party to bear the risk.

Practically, an employer may have considerable difficulty proving the circumstances in which damage occurred - often, the only evidence may be from the employee who the employer is alleging caused the damage.

**Conclusion**

In terms of a direct answer to the question, no, employees are certainly not liable for "wear and tear".

But employees are also not generally liable for any accidental damage, even if it isn't wear and tear. Whatever the employer gets back, is what it is.

It would be for a judge to decide whether particular circumstances fell below the standard of the employee's duty to take reasonable care of the employer's goods, but that is a very low standard.